# Log transformation for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, assumptions, normality-assumption

Is it necessary to log transform non-normally distributed variables to perform logistic regression? If so, when is it appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

The question is poorly informed.  Which variables do you refer to? If the response variable, that is a binary (zero or one) variable, so never normaly distributed, and normal distribution is not part of the assumptions of logistic regression. If you refer to the independent, or regressor variables, in logistic regression those are deterministic, if they have some distribution that is not modelled. So in that case, also, the answer is NO.

You might of course have some specific, subject-matter reason to transform, but you didnt tell us any specifics, so I cannot comment on that.